# Close a tab in accordion when click on another

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

I'm having trouble when I want to close a tab in my accordion by clicking on another tab of the same accordion.

```
<script>
$(".accordion").on("click", ".accordion-header", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle();
    $(".accordion-header").next().slideToggle();
});
</script>
```

it really behaves in a weird way!

my HTML structure of one tab is like that and i have 2 of them :

```
<div class="accordion">
<h2 class="accordion-header">Stream / Digital</h2>
<div class="accordion-content ul-list-platform">
<ul>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can we see a codepen or something ?

Comment: Share some more HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.accordion').find('.accordion-header').on('click', function(){

     //Expand or collapse this panel
     //500 is animation time

     $(this).next().slideToggle(500);

     //Hide the other panels

     $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp(500);

});
```

try something like this.

`.next()` expands the next element after the header h2 element that's has been clicked.

`.not($(this).next())` collapses any `accordion-content` element that isn't the one being clicked on.